# duplicated nodes while generating xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

Here is my problem generating xml with the wanted format (I have duplicated nodes): I have a table recording entity modifications which can be made on several columns at a time. For example, I have the following @my_table (we can see that 'modif 3' on 'entity 2' changed 2 columns at the same time, columns 5 and 6) :

```
| id_entity | id_modif  | id_column | new_value |
-------------------------------------------------    
| entity 1  | modif 1   | column 4  | coucou    |    
| entity 2  | modif 2   | column 1  | papa      |    
| entity 2  | modif 3   | column 5  | blabla    |    
| entity 2  | modif 3   | column 6  | toto      |
```

I have to write an xml select which returns the all the changes of a one of the entities. The expected xml format is the following :

```
<history>
  <id_entity></id_entity>
  <modifs>
    <modif>
      <id_modif></id_modif>
      <details>
        <column></column>
        <value></value>
      </details>
      <details></details>
      <details></details>
      ...
    </modif>
    <modif></modif>
    <modif></modif>
    ....
  </modifs>
</history>
```

example with @entity = 'entity 1' :

```
<history>
  <id_entity>entity 1</id_entity>
  <modifs>
    <modif>
      <id_modif>modif 1</id_modif>
      <details>
        <column>column 4</columns>
        <value>coucou</value>
      </details>
    </modif>
  </modifs>
</history>
```

example with @entity = 'entity 2' :

```
<history>
  <id_entity>entity 2</id_entity>
  <modifs>
    <modif>
      <id_modif>modif 2</id_modif>
      <details>
        <column>column 1</column>
        <value>papa</value>
      </details>
    </modif>
    <modif>
      <id_modif>modif 3</id_modif>
      <details>
        <column>column 5</column>
        <value>blabla</value>
      </details>
      <details>
        <column>column 6</column>
        <value>toto</value>
      </details>
    </modif>
  </modifs>
</history>
```

With the select I wrote (see code at the end of the post), the problem comes when a modification changes several columns : since in my table there are multile rows for the same modif_id, the result in the xml is the duplication of the concerned node :

```
-- What I Got ('modif 3' node is duplicated because in @my_table I have 2 rows with 'modif 3') :
<history>
  <id_entity>entity 2</id_entity>
  <modifs>
    <modif>
      <id_modif>modif 2</id_modif>
        <details column 1 />
    </modif>
    <modif>
      <id_modif>modif 3</id_modif>
        <details columns 5 />
        <details columns 6 />
    </modif>
    <modif>
      <id_modif>modif 3</id_modif>
        <details columns 5 />
        <details columns 6 />
    </modif>
  </modifs>
</history>

-- What I wanted (only one node 'modif 3' with 2 'details' nodes):
<history>
  <id_entity>entity 2</id_entity>
  <modifs>
    <modif>
      <id_modif>modif 2</id_modif>
        <details column 1 />
    </modif>
    <modif>
      <id_modif>modif 3</id_modif>
        <details columns 5 />
        <details columns 6 />
    </modif>
  </modifs>
</history>
```

I tried to add "distinct" in the select statment but it is not accepted.
Here is the complete runnable code if you want to play... :

```
declare @my_table table(
    id_entity varchar(10), 
    id_modif varchar(10),
    id_column varchar(15),
    new_value varchar(15))
insert into @my_table 
    select 'entity 1', 'modif 1', 'column 4', 'coucou' union
    select 'entity 2', 'modif 2', 'column 1', 'papa' union
    select 'entity 2', 'modif 3', 'column 5', 'blabla' union
    select 'entity 2', 'modif 3', 'column 6', 'toto'

declare @id_entity varchar(10) = 'entity 2'

select
    @id_entity as 'id_entity',
    (select 
        parent.id_modif as 'id_modif',
        (select distinct        
            child.id_column as 'column',
            child.new_value as 'value'
        from @my_table child
        where child.id_entity = @id_entity
        and child.id_modif = parent.id_modif
        for xml path ('details'), type ) '*'
    from @my_table parent
    where parent.id_entity = @id_entity
    for xml path ('modif'), root('modifs'), type ) '*'
    for xml path ('history'), type
```

Note : I found a workaround I show to my boss with a different xml structure, but this is the end of a very long process which would be too long to modify....

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try gouping:

```
SELECT 
    t.id_entity,
    (
        SELECT 
            p.id_modif,
            (
                SELECT 
                    h.id_column,
                    h.new_value
                FROM @my_table h
                WHERE p.id_modif = h.id_modif
                FOR XML PATH('details'), TYPE
            )
        FROM @my_table AS p
        WHERE t.id_entity = p.id_entity
        GROUP BY p.id_modif
        FOR XML PATH('modif'), TYPE
    ) AS modifs
FROM @my_table AS t
WHERE t.id_entity = @id_entity
GROUP BY t.id_entity
FOR XML PATH('history'), type
```